# Unwanted newline added in a table when adding second control to a tablecell

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I'm creating a table in asp.net

```
Table tbl = new Table();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var tr = new TableRow();

    var lmc = new Menu();
    lmc.Width = Unit.Pixel(120);
    lmc.MenuItemClick +=lmc_MenuItemClick;
    lmc.Items.Add(new MenuItem(item.name));
    var tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Controls.Add(lmc);
    tc.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = item.description });
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    tbl.Rows.Add(tr);                    

}

placeholder.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

my HTML looks like this for one row:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="[a source]" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="">
        <ul class="level1">
            <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack([stuff])">Name</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><a id="_SkipLink"></a><span>Description</span></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

When running this code the expected result is:

```
[name][description]
[name][description]
.....
```

but what I'm getting is

```
[name]
[description]
[name]
[description]
.....
....
```

Why am I getting a newline for each `description` that is added?

Comment: The code you've got there is very odd - you're not *doing* anything with the table cell you create, and you're adding the table row without putting anything in it. You also appear to have a rogue closing brace. I suspect that's not your actual code...

Comment: could you please show the resulting HTML? Because it depends what HTML is rendered with the Menu control. Anyway, I would use a hyperlink instead of a Menu...

Comment: Sorry, this is not the resulting HTML which is rendered in the browser. Please right click in your browser and show the HTML source code of your page :)

Comment: And the code *still* doesn't do anything with `tc`. (Look at what you're doing with `tr`: you create it, and add it to the table, but don't add anything into it.)

Comment: @Jürgen updated. But I can't really change anything in the html, its the codebehind that generates the html. I see that there's no br after the menu so I guess the menucontrols adds a br implicity after itself?

Comment: @JonSkeet oh sorry I guess I removed to much code be of course there should be an add.

Comment: I strongly suggest you try to come up with a complete project which does *nothing* but produce the table - you can then post the complete method in question, so we can definitely see *everything* relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the UL tag creates an line break. This is the default behavior of all HTML block elements: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

As already proposed: Don't use a Menü control. Use a simple HyperLink control or a HyperLinkButton instead, which creates a simple  HTML A tag.